# The ending of Silence

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, silence

What is the significance of the cross in the main character's hand when he is cremated given that he chose to give up his faith?

Though I understand the symbolism, I don't get the point! Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Don't worry, there's no need to hide your question behind an empty box. People who don't want to know the ending of *Silence* won't click on a question that's titled "The ending of Silence".

Comment: I haven't seen the movie but the Wikipedia entry seems to suggest that the main character doesn't *actually* renounce his faith....just appears to do so with Christ's blessing.

Comment: The film is also an adaption of a 1966 novel of the same name. So one might be able to find an answer there depending on how different or similar the endings are.

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigues never repudiates Christ in his heart, only in his actions (Christ himself gave him permission to do so). Thus, though he had to keep it to himself, he was a Christian to the end.